# Set time delay between two frames on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, setinterval, mouseout

I have to display two images for single `mouseover`. So when I `mouseover` to the image, first, the image is displayed then with a time delay of 5000, the image is needed to display for that same hover. Now on `mouseout` display the original image.

I am not so familiar with JavaScript and jQuery.
Can someone please give me some idea about how to do this.

What i did is,

```
 $('.image1').mouseover(function() {

    setInterval($(this).removeClass(.image1).addClass('image-over1'),5000);
    $(this).removeClass(.image1).addClass('image-over2');

    });
   $('.image1').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('image-over1');  
    $(this).removeClass('image-over2').addClass(item);
    });


   $('.image1').click(function(){
    document.location='index.php?page='index.php'; 
    })
```

Comment: if you could edit your question and ensure you put 4 spaces in front of all the bits that are source code... it makes it easier to understand what you are doing since this would make the code formatter display nicely for us.  Alternatively, highlight the code bits and click on the 10101 icon in the editor.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.hover()` function lets you specify both mouseover/mouseout at the same time, and you need to make a function for the `setInterval`:

```
$('.image1').hover(function(evt) {

  // mouse over function.

  // DOM Element that got the mouseover.
  var target = evt.target; 

  if (target.timer) {
    clearTimeout(target.timer);
    target.timer = null;
  }

  target.timer = setInterval(function() {

       // $(this) will not work here, since 'this' has changed.
       // depending on your css you shouldn't need to remove the '.image1'
       // class, just make sure .image-over1 and .image-over2 are
       // stronger selectors, or occur after .image1
       $('.image1').addClass('image-over2');    

       // at this point your element will be (just guessing <img>, could be
       // anything really:
       // <img class="image1 image-over1 image-over2" .../>

       // it's absolutely fine for the image to have all those classes as
       // long as your css is correct.       

   }, 5000);

    $('.image1').addClass('image-over1');

}, function(evt) {

   // mouse out function.

  // DOM Element that got the mouseout.
  var target = evt.target; 

  if (target.timer) {
    clearTimeout(target.timer);
    target.timer = null;
  }

   $('.image1').removeClass('image-over1');
   $('.image1').removeClass('image-over2');

 });


$('.image1').click(function(){ document.location='index.php?page='index.php'; })
```

Comment: thank you Martin. The effect is seen but the effect goes to infinite loop when the mouse is out. how to stop the infinite loop. Plz help me

Comment: Also plz mention how to go back to the original state with the same time interval.

Comment: Ok I'll add a cancel for the timeout.

Comment: There's probably a much terser way of doing what you want using jQuery all the way. Look at `jQuery.delay()` etc.

Comment: Martin it didnt work properly. For mouseover it works perfectly but when mouse is out it stops working.while removing the mouse the two frames shoud be rmoved one by one. any idea for this.

Comment: You need to make a similar timeout to the one setting the classes for the one removing. That way you can make an animation on mouseout too. Brush up on the documentation around setTimeout(), clearTimeout(), and it should be trivial to follow from where the code is. I leave that as an exercise for you :)

Comment: what is the value of target.timer?? when alert is says undefined.

Comment: thank you so much Martin for your prompt reply. It worked fine now.

Comment: target.timer is an id of the timer, a reference to this id must be set to be able to clearTimeout() to cancel the timer.

Comment: i want to continue the loading of two images until the mouse is hovered. when i mouse over to image then, loading of image-over1 and image-over2 continues until the mouse is removed. plz help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think there's a problem in your approach; if you remove the "image1" class from the element on a mouseover, then that element won't be matched by the $(".image1") selector for the mouseout. Is there a reason you need to remove it? If you do (i.e. if there is something defined on the class in the CSS that you need to disable), is there some other selector you could match on?

As to the time delay, if you're using a jQuery version greater than 1.4, you can use the .delay() function:

```
$('.image1').mouseover(function() {
 $(this).addClass('image-over1').delay(5000).addClass('image-over2');
});
```

Comment: my jquery version is 1.3.2 . I cannot modify the jquery since it affcts the other code . can u suggest me some other way. ALso when mouse is out the two frame shuould go back to the original state with the same time delay as i am trying to give the animation effect to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you to create an animated GIF of these images??? Then use a code similar to here: http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol3/design_no10.htm

Answer (score 0):

Even if the images are generated on fly, it is possible to programtically generate animated gif in PHP - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php